# Is NSNull equal to NSNull

Tags: objective-c, nsnull

Is [[NSNull null] isEqual:[NSNull null]] == YES?

What is the proper way to test if an id is NSNull. As well, if checking two collections for equality and they both contain NSNulls, will they still be considered equal?

Comment: The expression is not even syntactically correct.

Comment: I have fixed the syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you meant:

```
[[NSNull null] isEqual:NSNull]
```

No, `NSNull` is a class, not an object. You can't meaningfully compare it to `[NSNull null]`. You will always get the same object back from `[NSNull null]`, though - it's a singleton.  From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSNull/null):

> `+ (NSNull *)null`
>   **Return Value**
>   The singleton instance of NSNull.

So that means this expression:

```
[NSNull null] == [NSNull null]
```

Always returns `1`.  Likewise:

```
[[NSNull null] isEqual:[NSNull null]]
```

Will return `YES`.

Example:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(void)
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSLog(@"%d", [[NSNull null] isEqual:[NSNull null]]);
        NSLog(@"%d", [NSNull null] == [NSNull null]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Building & running:

```
$ clang example.m -o example -framework Foundation
$ ./example 
2013-08-30 14:56:21.200 example[27901:707] 1
2013-08-30 14:56:21.201 example[27901:707] 1
```

Comment: I fixed the syntax in the question

Comment: Then yes, you should get `YES` back.  But you don't need `isEqual` - simple pointer comparison will work, since it's a singleton.